# Sound activity level from the microphone with only javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, android-activity, microphone

Actually I'm trying to create a sound activity level from the mic. No record just a live level. I found many topics but nothing using only javascript. I found many useful links but I have no idea how to create what I want with just only javascript. The application need to work on several mobile platforms. (WebOS, Androïd, IOS...) and eventually on computers.

here are the links :

http://jsfiddle.net/7D3YS/

This link is a simple random leveler. It's look like what I want. But there is no control on the level.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureAudio

It's using an audio capture, I think it's the best way but I have no idea how to listen and create a graphical render.

www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/example1.html

This example is exactly what I want but it's using a swf file. And it doesn't work on iPhone.

www.filosophy.org/2011/03/talking-to-the-web-the-basics-of-html5-speech-input/

Google has created a webkit but I don't know how I can use it in my work.

I thank to record an audio file and listen this file at the same time but I'm not sure of the efficiency.

That's all what I found.
Thanks for your help!

Bastien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PhoneGap documentation points out, javascript cannot access the mic input from most devices (unless an api is specified for it). Phonegap will attempt to launch the audio input software on the device.

TLDR: You cannot directly access mic input with javascript, unless the device exposes an API for it.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. I'm using the API of PhoneGap on devices, there is no problem with that; but I have no idea on how to create a graphical render that's the main problem.

Comment: As PhoneGap documentation you linked points out, it uses the device audio recording application. Unless the device application exposes an API javascript can use, you will not get access to the raw input to display a render. iOS does not have a default recording application, as pointed out by PhoneGap, same goes with some blackberry devices.

Comment: Saying you can't do anything without an API is tautological.  What he's looking for is a phonegap plugin (built-in or third party) that exposes an API for sound levels.